# iTextSharp XFA Flattening - Linethrough font style not being preserved

Tags: itext

I have an XFA form that was designed in Adobe LiveCycle that I am trying to flatten with iTextSharp.  The linethrough font style is not being preserved in the flattened PDF.  The text is still there, but it doesnt have the linethrough anymore, so I think this could potentially be a bug in the new XFA worker.  Any ideas?

Comment: XFA Worker is a closed source product (you can't use it without a commercial license). Please address questions like this to pre-sales. We have fixed plenty of small glitches like the one you mention for future customers.

Comment: Bruno, With all due respect, I am a current customer and my organization has already purchased the XFA worker.  I am just looking for help on this issue because we are experiencing this in our production environment...

Comment: In that case, please create a support ticket on the issue tracker for customers (JIRA). The XFA team is not on StackOverflow.